# Python OCR Module in Linux?

Tags: python, ocr

I want to find a easy-to-use OCR python module in linux, I have found pytesser http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/, but it contains a .exe executable file.

I tried changed the code to use wine, and it really works, but it's too slow and really not a good idea.

Is there any Linux alternatives that as easy-to-use as it?

Comment: Why closing the question? It surely fit in "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" defined in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just wrap `tesseract` in a function:

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

def ocr(path):
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    process = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', path, temp.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    process.communicate()

    with open(temp.name + '.txt', 'r') as handle:
        contents = handle.read()

    os.remove(temp.name + '.txt')
    os.remove(temp.name)

    return contents
```

If you want document segmentation and more advanced features, try out [OCRopus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/).

Comment: That code is wrong, `handle.close()` calls `str.close()` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Gotcha. I re-wrote it a little while I was writing this, as I had two `.close()` functions which were taking up space. Not sure if it's bad to omit them, but I've heard that Python cleans up all by itself.

Comment: yes, the pytesser is also something like your function that shells the tesseract executable file and gets stdout back. But tessetact.exe uses a temp file that stop me from using multi-threading(file conflict)

Comment: Hmm, how would you multi-thread? It's not supported in Tesseract (AFAICT, but the svn version of Tesseract worked wonders for me with it's layout-analysis), and since I use a tempfile, it's unique and won't conflict.

Comment: Maybe a different method would work? What are you trying to accomplish through this module?

Comment: I have lots of different image files and using threading.Thread and Queue to multi-thread. Thank you and I'll try your func with svn version of tesseract.

Comment: Could you show an example of how to use `ocr()` function please

Comment: @david_adler: `ocr('path/to/your/image.png')`?

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Blender's answer, that just executs Tesseract executable, I would like to add that there exist other alternatives for OCR that can also be called as external process.

ABBYY comand line OCR utility: http://ocr4linux.com/en:start

It is not free, so worth to consider only if Tesseract accuracy is not good enough for your task, or you need more sophisticated layout analisys or you need to export PDF, Word and other files.

**Update: here's comparison of ABBYY and tesseract accuracy: http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-06/15-linux_ocr_software_comparison**

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY

Comment: I'd argue that Tesseract has better accuracy than ABBY FineReader, as I've used both to digitize a few hundred books.

Comment: @Blender: Here's comparison of several engines: http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-06/15-linux_ocr_software_comparison You can see that ABBYY far more accurate in general, giving 100% accuracy on most of the samples, but still there are areas where it is worse than tesseract. My experience shows same: ABBYY in general is indeed way more accurate, and (what is most important for me) works well even without training. Did you train tesseract for a document? And did you also train ABBYY or compared with just as it is?

Comment: No training for Tesseract at all. But I'm using the `svn` version of Tesseract, which is much different that the normal stable build.

Comment: I tested `tesseract` with those images, and it has only 2 characters which differ from the original. ABBYY works for printed text well, but for cruddy typed text that I took a picture of, Tesseract works a bit better. Other than that, I don't have the money to buy ABBYY ;)

Answer (score 6):

python tesseract

http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import tesseract

api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)

image=cv.LoadImage("eurotext.jpg", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
tesseract.SetCvImage(image,api)
text=api.GetUTF8Text()
conf=api.MeanTextConf()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try the excellent scikits.learn libraries for machine learning. You can find two codes that are ready to run [here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/auto_examples/manifold/plot_lle_digits.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of options here.

One way, as others pointed out is to use tesseract. Looks like there are a bunch of wrappers by now, so best way is to [do a quick pypi search](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=tesser&submit=search) for it. The most used ones these days are:

- [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract/0.1.5)
- [pytesser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserpy/1.1.1)
- [tesserwrap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserwrap/0.1.6)
- [pyocr](https://github.com/jflesch/pyocr)

Another useful site for finding similar engines is [alternative.to](http://alternativeto.net/software/ocropus/). A few linux based systems according to them are:

- ABBYY
- Tesseract
- CuneiForm
- Ocropus
- GOCR