# Extract small Arial text from screenshot

Tags: python, ocr

I need to automate a extract of info from a Flash App. My idea was to take a screenshot and get the text from there, but using Pytesser isn't working (it returns nothing, don't know if it's because i'm doing something wrong or because it's too small).

The text is **black arial size 8 text** in a white background, no noise, and the text is pretty simple (mostly things like "9:32" or "Cristiano Ronaldo"). How would you face this problem in a simple way and using Python?

Just in case it's needed, i'm using Windows XP and Python 2.7

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you any code on how you extract the screenshot? or is that an external application doing the work, or even manually?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799946/python-ocr-module-in-linux

Comment: I'm using PIL to take the screenshot and grab the interesting part. I'll take a look to that post, thanks!

Comment: If the text is too small, try 'blowing up' the pixels, for example 2x or 3x.  That should produce sufficient font size for any OCR to read.  However, 8 points is usually OK for a modern OCR (not sure about the one you are using).